# "Unable to create Ubuntu Menu Proxy" using GVim in Ubuntu

Tags: vim, ubuntu

I am getting this error in the terminal window when trying

```
$ gvim
** (gvim:2350): WARNING **: Unable to create Ubuntu Menu Proxy: Timeout was reached
```

gvim launches but then this error occurs. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: It doesn't look like a Vim error. You should consider moving this to [askubuntu](http://askubuntu.com/).

Comment: askubuntu: http://askubuntu.com/questions/132977/how-to-get-global-application-menu-for-gvim

Answer (score 14):

The reason you are getting is because Gvim doesn't have an appmenu in Ubuntu by default. You can fix this by adding a global menu for Gvim.

Running the command `UBUNTU_MENUPROXY= gvim` instead of `gvim` will help you get rid of that warning. You can also consider aliasing gvim to the above command.

For more information, see [How to get global application menu for gvim?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/132977/how-to-get-global-application-menu-for-gvim)